# Can we [bypass] this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Stumbled on [bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bypass) today when someone tried to edit the tag wiki. There are only a small number of questions, and the actual topics are quite varied. Just flagging it for the attention of more avid meta users.

Comment: There's at least a handful of things in that tag that should be closed/deleted *before* the tag is just edited out of questions.  **Don't edit the tag out carte-blanche** since we're not going to see those questions again.  Take the time to do the extra moderation on them.

Comment: I'm not going to do anything, just raising it for whoever wants to take care of it.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a whole process we have to go through [documented here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/1079354) which seems to get missed when these kinds of things come up...

Comment: Removed the tag suggesting that I wanted to initiate that process then... Someone more zealous than me can initialize the "formal" process if they want...

Comment: You can leave the Burninate tag in your question. In fact, without it, there's a near-0 chance this will ever be seen or acted upon once it falls off the front page

Answer (score 12):

This is definitely a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). [bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bypass) isn't adding anything of value to the questions, and its meaning is different in most contexts

20 questions, some of which are off-topic. I say quick burninate.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44973902/1997232) is ok to stay, perhaps rename a bit `[bypass-library]`?

Comment: @Sinatr We could delete the tag straight up and not affect the question (and a better tag would be something like [android-bypass] in this case, but I don't think we need it). Burninate does not mean delete all the questions. We try to save good questions like that with a retag.

Comment: @Machavity sadly the library is available for more than Android, it's also available on iOS. And since the name is generic, I don't believe that bypass library just cut it, so I extended it to name-object-kind, as bypass-markdown-library.

Comment: @Braiam Works for me