# Should we [bypass] this tag (again!)?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bypass) tag was *already* removed [five years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365933/can-we-bypass-this-tag). Unfortunately, it's here again. I propose that we burninate it a second time. Arguably, we should block it too.

---

Criteria:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. This tag is ambiguous. Presumably the OP wants to bypass *something*, but that isn't descriptive.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Not really. Or, sometimes? This tag is too vague anyways.

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

IMO, no.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Absolutely no. It can refer to

- Users trying to bypass ISP restrictions
- Bypassing filters, like Cloudflare
- Bypassing VPNs
- Dealing with Captchas
- Etc.

---

It has under 50 questions, so we can expedite the burnination, but I need to

- Have authoritative knowledge of technologies associated with the tag - I feel there are no technologies specifically associated with this tag, so N/A
- Confer with a [20K user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Given that, I feel it should be burninated. Agree? Disagree? Thoughts?

---

**Note**: this is not a burnination invitation, it is a discussion.

Anyone that tries to go and ignore the process risks moderator action. You have been warned. Yes, the process is cumbersome. That is  *not* a reasonable reason to flat-out ignore it. There is [an official process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) to follow *before* we can burninate it. I am starting a *discussion*, not inviting users to *actually burninate it*.

Comment: we're trying to avoid a [triple-bypass] here

Answer (score 28, accepted):

...am I a 20k user?  I have trusted user privileges...

Anyway, yeah, [what Machavity said last time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365979/208273) is true this time as well: It "isn't adding anything of value to the questions, and its meaning is different in most contexts".

To the extent that there is a theme that could hypothetically be a tag, there are a lot of questions about bypassing websites' bot protections, which... I don't thiiiink we should have a dedicated tag for?  The subject is basically entirely about defeating abuse protections, which...maybe we shouldn't be encouraging?  It's also likely to constantly change as workarounds are defeated.  Disclosure: a division of my employer makes CAPTCHA software, so... unbiased opinions welcome on that.

Anyway, here are the questions about bypassing CAPTCHAs, in case anyone has any useful tagging ideas:

- [How can I Bypass the re-captcha on a website in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74469070/how-can-i-bypass-the-re-captcha-on-a-website-in-cypress)
- [How to bypass hCaptha with accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762309/how-to-bypass-hcaptha-with-accessibility)
- [Unable to bypass captcha with 2captcha result key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376725/unable-to-bypass-captcha-with-2captcha-result-key)
- [Bypass Facebook reCAPTCHA when create account using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76769168/bypass-facebook-recaptcha-when-create-account-using-selenium)

And here is bypassing Cloudflare's (bot?) protection, another theme that I don't think we need a tag for:

- [How can I bypass nowsecure.nl via requests lib in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74497589/how-can-i-bypass-nowsecure-nl-via-requests-lib-in-python) (probably, based on the tags)
- [Problems with cloud flare 403 and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440433/problems-with-cloud-flare-403-and-python)
- [hey Im new with selenuim and i couldn't make a bot that logs into a website with cloudflare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72637396/hey-im-new-with-selenuim-and-i-couldnt-make-a-bot-that-logs-into-a-website-with)
- [How to bypass Cloudflare security using httpx request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510629/how-to-bypass-cloudflare-security-using-httpx-request)

The rest are...sort of a random mish-mash of topics.

Also, there were a bunch of off-topic questions, which I closed.  Also some unclear ones.

Comment: I guess my conclusion would be burn+denylist the tag so that it can't be recreated a third time.  If there is any value from any theme of these, it should be in a specific [something-bypass] tag rather than a generic [bypass] tag.

Comment: IMO - any topic asking how to bypass something is better tagged with the thing in question that needs to be bypassed, rather than having tag(s) specific to bypassing.